# need to target 'delete' button to elements pouring out of a while loop in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, database, while-loop

I have the following loop, which creates a list from a database:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($tutor_subj);$i++){
$query_tutors = "SELECT level, subject FROM level, subject WHERE level.id = '$tutor_lvl[$i]' AND subject.id = '$tutor_subj[$i]'";       
$result_t = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query_tutors);
    while($m = mysqli_fetch_array($result_t)){
    echo $m['level']." ".$m['subject']." ".$tutor_top[$i]."<div style='float:right; padding-right:5px;'><a href='#'><img src='images/remove_btn.png' onclick='removeSubj'></a></div></br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

As you can see I'm adding a 'remove' button in the html after each entry, and I want to use this button to allow the users to delete that particular row of data from the database if they choose.

My question is how can I link the row from this while loop to the button being generated at the end of each line (so that the appropriate entry is deleted in the DB)?

PS - I havent written the javascript/jquery function removeSubj yet because I'm stuck, hence am not including that

Comment: You will need to use AJAX to send the data from client side to server side, and let the PHP script delete it from the table.

Comment: One easy way is to redirect the link of each button to a php file. Something like `<a href='delete.php?level='.$m['level'].'>`. Then in delete.php you would call the DB function to delete it.

Comment: @ashwinMukhija that's fine, but how can I make the server know what data to delete? i.e. how can I make each button specify each row of output?

Comment: @Akatosh thanks for that - but I wanted to do it via AJAX so that they could just click the button and the line vanishes

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can assign ids to the `<a>` tags through the loop for one, or you can wrap the content in a div with the id of the div set to be the ID of the entry, or if you feel a little more adventurous, you can easily use the `data` attribute of HTML5

Comment: thanks Ashwin - if I assign id's to the <a> tag then I can just select them with the standard jquery selector($('#id')) for the Ajax call right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an unique identifier to `onclick='removeSubj'` so that when it is called, you can determine what you would want to delete. You could use something like `onclick='removeSubj("unique_identifier")'`. Replace that unique_identifier with something that is always unique for every row in your database (for example an id-field).

You can then use this value in your javascript function, and finally in your server-side script, to delete the correct row.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you and example to buttress @sumurai8s' point because i had the same issue before i read his answer.

1. assuming this is the item you intend to loop (i.e you have dynamically generated this from your php/database loop)

   ```
   <div class="media-body media-right">
   <span onclick="delete(<?php echo $fromDb['id']; ?>);" class="icon icon-trash-o icon-3x text-blood pull-lg-right"></span>
   </div>
   ```
2. This is what your java script should be

   ```
   //delete
   function delete(I) {
       // delete methodology
               var id_to_be_deleted = I;
               var formData = new FormData();
               formData.append("id_to_be_deleted", id_to_be_deleted);
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/delete.php",
                   contentType: false,
                   processData: false,
                   //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data : formData,
                   success: function()
                   { 
                   alert('successs');
                   }
                   });
                  }
   ```
3. And **delete.php** should be

   ```
   <?php
   if ($_POST['id_to_be_deleted']) {
   $delete = $_POST['id_to_be_deleted'];
   //do db delete query here i.e DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id='$id_to_be_deleted'
   ...
   }
   ```
4. if you don't do it this way you might be experiencing your DELETE ACTION being fired twice.

Don't thank me, thank @sumurai8 for waking me up from my slumber ;)

Happy coding.